# Stat not properly showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am currently making an rpg, and commonly in rpg's, there are stat points, so I worked on that and I also worked on conversions like your HP is based on the amount of VIT you have, and it also works. The problem now is that I somehow can't display it on unity run time, it always displays zero, but the debug.log says otherwise.

This is the code for Displaying stats.

```
public class StatisticsViewer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerStatistics Statistics;
    public VitalityConverter vitalityConverter;

    public Text HP;
    public Text STR;
    public Text VIT;
    public Text Int;
    public Text Dex;
    public Text Spd;

    void Start()
    {
        vitalityConverter = FindObjectOfType<VitalityConverter>();
        if (vitalityConverter != null)
        {
            HP.text = vitalityConverter.CurrentHP.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("VitalityConverter missing!");
        }
        STR.text = Statistics.initialSTR.ToString();
        VIT.text = Statistics.initialVIT.ToString();
        Int.text = Statistics.initialInt.ToString();
        Dex.text = Statistics.initialDex.ToString();
        Spd.text = Statistics.initialSpd.ToString();
    }
}
```

And this is for Calculating Hp.

```
public class VitalityConverter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerStatistics CurrentStats;
    public int CurrentHP;

    private int ConversionRate = 5;

    void Start()
    {
        VitalityMathConversion();
        int healthValue = HealthValue();
        Debug.Log("Total Health is " + healthValue);
    }
    public void VitalityMathConversion()
    {
        
        CurrentHP = (CurrentStats.initialVIT + CurrentStats.CurrentVit) * ConversionRate;
    }

    public int HealthValue()
    {
        return CurrentHP;
    }
}
```

Did I miss something here? I've been scratching my head on this matter for a while now.

Comment: Please give example values, and what results you  get -  be sure in your converter that yourr conversion rate is not 0

Comment: also there are two different fields `PlayerStatistics` .. are you sure you are referencing the same instance in both?